# How to verify that the @PathVariable has acorresponding URI template variable in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Here is an example of a API method that wont work because no URI template variable exists for `bar`.

```
@RequestMapping("/example")
public String foo(@PathVariable String bar) {
    return bar;
}
```

I would like to know how can I write a test that looks at all of my `@Controller`s and checks that every method with a `@RequestMapping` has all of the required URI template variables for the `@PathVariable` annotations on the method. Such a test should be able to detect that the above method has an issue.

I guess what I would need to be able to do is:

- find all methods that are an API
- find out what the variables are for the `@RequestMapping` for the method (including looking at annotations on the class and parent classes)
- find out what the variable names are for the `@PathVariable`s

Comment: One way of doing it would the to process a GET-request in the test and see if the Statuscode is 400 or not.